# DENSE RANK should return NULL in case of previous duplicate value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, count, dense-rank

How below one can be achieved ?

```
select
    DENSE_RANK() over(order by Flt_OperativeFlight_Legs.DateSTA, Flt_OperativeFlight.FlightKey) SNo, 
    Flt_OperativeFlight.Flight_ID flightID ,
    Flt_OperativeFlight.FlightKey flight
from
    Flt_OperativeFlight inner join  
    Flt_OperativeFlight_Legs 
        on Flt_OperativeFlight.Flight_ID = Flt_OperativeFlight_Legs.Flight_ID inner join  
    Flt_OperativeFlight_Segments 
        on Flt_OperativeFlight.Flight_ID = Flt_OperativeFlight_Segments.Flight_ID 
where
    Flt_OperativeFlight_Legs.DateATA between '2020-05-25T09:00:00' and '2020-05-25T19:49:00'
```

**Current Results:**

```
SNo flightID flight
---------------------
1   757625  ET0567
1   757625  ET0567
2   744592  SQ0425
3   744390  MI0321
3   744390  MI0321
```

**Expecting Results:**

```
SNo  flightID flight
---------------------
1    757625 ET0567
NULL 757625 ET0567
2    744592 SQ0425
3    744390 MI0321
NULL 744390 MI0321
```

Comment: Just a hint use Case and Lag analytical function to check if previous dense_rank is same as current dense rank and then null.

Comment: This is anyway something that you'd usually not do in SQL, but in your GUI (i.e. in your app or Website).

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Yes but i want it in query for some other reason.

Comment: So what is wrong with the answers you have here? You want a "canonical answer", but don't define why the answers don't answer the problem.

Comment: @Larnu Answers not giving the expected results.

Comment: [Søren Kongstad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5453613/s%c3%b8ren-kongstad)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63450533/2029983) appears to work fine, @SantoshJadi : [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3d5f6deece8c1a41e303ef66aadd0b79). Can you explain *why* it doesn't work? If it isn't, then the question you have asked and the problem you are trying to solve are likely not the same.

Comment: can you post the table you're working with and the desired result?

Answer (score 4):

You can mix with another analytical function row_number, which guarantees unique numbers.

I partition by the key, so only one row number is 1

```
SELECT
    n
   ,IIF(
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY n ORDER BY n) = 1,
        DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY n)
        , NULL) rn
FROM (VALUES ('a'), ('a'), ('b'), ('c'), ('c'), ('c'), ('d')) a (n)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm comparing every `FlightDetails.Flight` to the `FlightDetails.Flight` before it and if they're the same then `null`.

```
select case lag(flightID) over (order by flightID desc) when flightID then null else SNo end as SNo
      ,flightID 
      ,flight
from   t
```

| SNo | flightID | flight |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 757625 | ET0567 |
| null | 757625 | ET0567 |
| 2 | 744592 | SQ0425 |
| 3 | 744390 | MI0321 |
| null | 744390 | MI0321 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=31f1b5f6306a1eeda926580ff181b458&hide=1)

Comment: Please make your answer more useful by adding an explanation of what it does and how it answers the question.

Comment: @miken32 I added something. Honestly, this question makes no sense. I think his original query is problematic and that's why he needs to "fix it" with another query. Presenting the data in this manner doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any test data to test this with but the idea is it should be using the `LAG` analytical function

```
select case when prev_sno = sno then NULL
else sno end as sno from (
select lag(sno) over(order by sno) prev_sno, sno from (
 select
        DENSE_RANK() over(
    order by 
      FlightLegInformation.DateSTA,
     IncomingFlightSegments.FlightKey
  ) SNo)) ,
```

Comment: Don't you mean `THEN NULL`, not `then 'null'`? `NULL` and `'null'` are completely different values; and the latter is not a `NULL` value. Considering, that `sno` appears to be a `int` as well, this would return an error along the lines of `Unable to implicitly cast varchar value 'null' to int.`

Comment: I meant NULL yes.

Comment: Thanks for reply but does not help.

Comment: Please add sample data.

Comment: *"I meant NULL yes."* Then you should change your answer to `NULL`, not `'null'`.

Comment: @Santosh Jadi: "It does not help" ... because? Are you getting an error? Or wrong results? Or it works, but you don't understad why? Any other reason?